# jquery blockUI and asp.net submit button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have developed a payment processing form where user fills the payment details and submit the button "Pay Now" ..what i want is to block the entire UI with the message "Processing Payment..." and with a slight delay right after payment processing stored procedure executes (in code behind) it should UNBLOCK the UI. Actually i was having multiple postbacks from user due to the slight delay ...I dont want to disable button. how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have a look at the BlockUI-Plugin?

http://jquery.malsup.com/block/

Comment: yes..i made a javascript function with .blockUI function..like this.
 function Openpaymentmsg() {
        $.blockUI({ message: $('#domMessage') }); 
    }
and calling the function from code behind using

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Openpaymentmsg", "Openpaymentmsg()", true);

Comment: somehow its not coming up..i guess something is wrong with the DIV element..humm